# Reverse every array in an array of arrays in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have an array of arrays of strings (`[[String]]`). I want to reverse each array inside the large array.

```
var players = [["A","B","C","D"],["E","F","G","H"], ["J","K","L","M"]]
```

**Wanted result:**

```
[["D","C","B","A"],
["H","G","F","E"],
["M","L","K","J"]]
```

Comment: Yeah, homework question with no attempt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should iterate through every element with `map` and reverse them.

```
let playersReversed = players.map { $0.reversed() }
```

Keep in mind that this will return an array of reversed collections and not an array of arrays of strings. To do that, convert the result of the reversion to `Array`:

```
let playersReversed = players.map { Array($0.reversed()) }
```

Comment: Thank you for your rapid response! You are the greatest!